# Greasemonkey script to trigger every time a new query is put through Google Instant

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, google-search

Massive irony here is I started writing this script as an answer to another question on the StackExchange network.

I'm writing a Greasemonkey Script which I want to run on Google search results.
Whenever a user searches for something I wish the script to run the command.

```
document.querySelector(".lr_dct_spkr > input:nth-child(1)").click();
```

*Autplays the audio when you query "define x" into Google*

However I realised quickly that simply writing this into the bottom of the script means it only gets triggered when search results load for the first time, and I need it to trigger every time a new query (or set of search results appear). I initially thought this may be an Ajax problem and tried to solve it using a waitForKeyElement function but I cannot seem to trigger it no matter what kind of element I wait for (The best element to wait for would be the cards that that the definitions appear on, but it doesn't really matter what element).

```
// @include     www.google.com/*
// @require https://git.io/vMmuf
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
$.waitForKeyElements ("div.lr_dct_ent_ph",launchsound);

function launchsound(){
    document.querySelector(".lr_dct_spkr > input:nth-child(1)").click();
}
```

I then worked out that Google doesn't even use Ajax, but this solution should work anyway?

TL:DR: **How do I write a script that triggers every time a new search query is put into google instant?**

Comment: do you mean to trigger: while user types search query; after user typed search query; after user hits search button; or after results page loads?

Comment: Each time the results page loads a different set of results (i.e after user hits the search button)

Comment: If my answer was an insufficient solution, please let me know so that I can help you find a better solution. If you are pleased with the solution provided, don't forget to check mark the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Parse URL to find out if a search query has been responded to, i.e. are you on the results page.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    My Userscript
// @include https://www.google.com/search?*
// @require https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/URI.js/1.18.10/URI.min.js
// @grant   GM_setValue
// @grant   GM_getValue

// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var currentSearch = URI.parseQuery(window.location.search).q;
    var lastSearch = GM_getValue('lastSearch');
    if (currentSearch != lastSearch) {
        GM_setValue('lastSearch', currentSearch);
        console.log('Do Whatever You Want HERE');
    }
})();
```